# What is the best way to turn off the Ubuntu beep permanently?

Tags: ubuntu

I've seen different ways to turn off the annoying Ubuntu beep but what is the best way to turn it off permanently through software?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu beep?

Comment: the noise the pc speaker on system error

Comment: system error  ?

Comment: Who is responsible for this bell??

Comment: The PC speaker beep should be made illegal by international law.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**disable the warning beep**
you can do so by editing your `/etc/rc.local` file. Open the file in your editor of choice and go all the way to the bottom of the file. At the bottom there should be a line which reads exit 0. Add a new line directly above this one and put this on that line:

```
modprobe -r pcspkr
```

Save the file and this will turn off the system beep. If you want to turn the system beep back on, just edit this file again and remove the line that was added.

**(OR)**

You can disable this by editing a file and entering two simple lines.

```
gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

And then add:

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

Save your file and the speaker beep will be gone when you reboot.

If you don’t want to wait until a reboot, simply type:

```
sudo rmmod pcspkr
```

**(OR)**

You can disable system bell if in the Terminal you go to Edit->Current Profile->General and uncheck the Terminal Bell
Or in the Configuration editor go to apps->Gnome-Terminal->Profiles->default check silent Bell.

**(OR)**

Edit the `.inputrc` file in your home directory (create it if needed) and add the line

```
set bell-style visible
```

You can also add (or uncomment) this line in the general /etc/inputrc file to set the bell-style for all users (overriden in ~/.inputrc).

Comment: This also works: xset -b

Comment: Is that period "." supposed to be at the end of "modprobe -r pcspkr"?

Comment: The file is `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` in on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. However as `pcspkr` is blacklisted by default and the beep is there nevertheless for me I supppose it's the BIOS setting for “power events” one has to change, see [How to turn off beep on suspend in xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283809/how-to-turn-off-beep-on-suspend-in-xubuntu).

Comment: Too much noise in this outdated answer. `/etc/rc.local` for example is not anymore there.

Comment: Only the bell-style thing worked for me. But it did work, so +1

Answer (score 25):

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 20.04:

Enter Terminal's menu:
[image]

Then "preferences" > (Active profile, it's under profiles with a check mark) > "text" (tab) > "sound" > "terminal bell" and unchecking it fixed the issue.

Comment: I also had to change the font and colors, so this is the easiest of all for me.

Comment: OP asked for system-wide disabling of this bell. Not just in terminal.

Comment: Observation / feedback: The neatly enumerated methods from joe's answer ( previous answer above ) could either not be implemented on Ubuntu 20.04 or did not produce the desired result ( despite this: thank you joe ). What does seem to work on Ubuntu 20.04 is Iman Mohamadi's recommendation.

Comment: This answers works to deactivate the bell inside the Terminal. It doesn't work for the bell sound in other app, like Files for example.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 16, search the applications for Sound, click on "sound effects" tab, Set the alert volume under that tab to "Off"

Answer (score 4):

Disconnect the PC speaker inside the Chassis.

That is the simple answer.

Comment: Maybe because the OP asked for a software solution...

Comment: Try doing it in a laptop without messing up. Your answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "_That is the simple answer._" Depends. Editing `~/.inputrc` took me a few seconds (and can be automated for installing new computers), while finding a screw driver to open my pc would take me much longer. And the system error/beep/bell is not always played through the PC speaker so it wouldn't work in that case. And obviously this solution disables more than just the system beep. I understand this could be an acceptable solution for some users, but it's kinda overkill and certainly not the simplest one.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to disable the `pcspkr` driver, that way you don't have to undo any hardware changes in the future. 
Open up a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
```

Then, if you want to avoid doing this every time after rebooting, append the following line to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file. *If it's not there, create it.*

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

Comment: This absolutely does not work on ubuntu 18.04.2!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this answer over on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/26405/how-do-i-turn-off-the-beep-in-the-terminal-in-linux)

Disconnecting the speaker works too ;)