# Disabling all sounds and beeps on Linux

Tags: linux

Under Linux - 
Is there a simple way of disabling all beeps for all applications?

A coworker near me has a Linux computer that beeps a lot. It's running a scheduled task that runs for several hours, and beeps constantly - it can beep *dozens of times per minute*. Somehow she and other workers can live with the constant beeping, but frankly, this drives me nut crazy. The program causing the beeps isn't a shell script, it's a homemade gui program.

I assume it is an old production server, and the job it does is important, so I'd prefer a minimal impart solution, preferably without restarting.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The server starts at weekends and runs until Sunday (work day here), so I can only check this next week. I'll be back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean the PC Speaker beep, because the beep in a connected speaker would be easy to remove by just turning off the speakers.

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/26405/how-do-i-turn-off-the-beep-in-the-terminal-in-linux) on server fault, but the jist of it is:

```
modprobe -r pcspkr
```

on the command line, and add

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

Newer kernels use the `snd_pcsp` module instead, so if it doesn't work, try the same two things as above except with `snd_pcsp` in the place of `pcspkr`

Comment: Note: this question is also a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently , which may need a retitle or something

Comment: For me (Ubuntu 9.04) this still worked with pcspkr.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's a GUI program, you can just type "xset b off" in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly Linux-specific, but I've been known to unplug the speaker wires from the motherboard.  Unfortunately, not all computers like to be opened up while running.

Answer (score 1):

Most motherboards have a beeper somewhere on them, this sounds if you haven't connected the one on the case. (this is an extra beeper, nothing to do with soundcards or 'real' speakers in some more expensive cases)  Removing the pcspkr module will only work if it is compiled as module and not built into the kernel.