# Silencing the Kubuntu PC Speaker beep

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to turn off the Ubuntu beep permanently?](https://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently)

My Kubuntu installation makes me jump every now and then by emitting a hideous beep - generally when I reach the limit of a text field etc. How can I turn it off? I have tried the following:

```
sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
sudo rmmod pcspkr
```

And I have added the following into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`:

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

But the beep persists...

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to see [this question's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/15770/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-off-the-ubuntu-beep-permanently) for further details. As it is also on SuperUser I do not believe I need to paste the content here.

I would go the /etc/inputrc route.

Answer (score 0):

you ran "update-modules" after blacklisting the module?

Comment: Er... no. I need to do that then? :-)

Comment: http://www.wlug.org.nz/update-modules(8).

which modules are loaded or not should be controlled by /etc/modules.conf... which is created by update-modules from entries in /etc/modules.d/* or whatever the distro is using